# Crash when initializing vector with one element using brace initialization in VS2019

Tags: c++

The following code crashes deep inside the standard library:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

struct Parent
{
    std::set<int> v;
};

struct Child : public Parent
{
    Child() = default;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Child> v{ {} };
}
```

but if the constructor is explicitly declared (without = default), it doesn't crash. I don't understand why.
I'm using VS2019.

Comment: Here is an example: https://rextester.com/SWP16423  If you run it in the debugger it dies at  `inline void _Container_base12::_Orphan_all() noexcept` in xmemory.h  but that's inside a `#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2`

Comment: Huh, this seems to crash with VS2019, but not with Clang++. Probably undefined behaviour? Edit: and from Jerry's comment, it does not crash with GCC

Comment: Also `Child c = *std::initializer_list<Child>{ {} }.begin();` causes the same crash, but not `std::initializer_list<Child>{ Child{} }`

Comment: It also crashes if the add a default constructor to the parent, and then try create the parent class

Comment: Using a std::vector does not crash either... this is bizarre

Comment: Seems like a bug: https://rextester.com/QJJG77831 shows that the set is being destroyed before it is copied from, and it is being destroyed twice (bad copy elision?)

Comment: The same set gets destroyed twice, once from the vector destructor then again in main, strangely I can see a copy constructor in the debugger, definitely one for microsoft to debug

Comment: It works in 2017

Comment: The bug report: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Crash-when-initializing-vector-with-one-/1248588?entry=myfeedback

Comment: @Michael I have tested this code with Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.3. It is working fine. It seems the bug is fixed now.

Comment: Someone who worked on resolving this that it's a compiler bug and that it's been fixed should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up into the code and it really caused to happen in Visual Studio 16.7.7. Now it seems to be working fine in both in VS 16.8.3 and g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0 (tried with -std=c++14), it was a bug which seems to be fixed by Microsoft team in the recent update.